# Why my bundle file is so big in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

You can see some files and their detailed info in Webpack, and some files are very large.
Why does that happen?

I use these plugins in my production environment and nothing else.
My guess is that is maybe caused by SCSS file or pictures.

[image]

Comment: A common cause for this is [`devtool` configuration](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool) that includes a (large) source map in the bundle. But without specifics about your project (webpack config and which modules you use in your code), it's difficult to say.

Comment: Run this and see what is in the bundle: https://github.com/th0r/webpack-bundle-analyzer